# how to save filters data and don't get lost when refreshing page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I would like to know if it is possible to save the filters that I make and that when I refresh my page, my filter is kept saved

this is my filter function it works correctly. but what I'm looking for is that when I refresh the website and reopen the modal, my filter will remain

```
function filter() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'example.php',
            data: { 
                'oper'  : 'filters',
                'id' : $("#id").val(),
                'filter1' : $("#filter1").val(),
                'filter2' : $("#filter2").val(),
                'filter3' : $("#filter3").val(),
                'filter4' : $("#filter4").val(),
                'filter5' : $("#filter5").val(),
                'filter6' : $("#filter6").val(),
            },
            success: function (response) {
                $('#modal-1').fadeOut(500);
                $('#modal-1').html(response);
                $('#modal-1').fadeIn(500);
            },
            error: function () {
                swal({title: "Error",text: "Oops Error", type: "error"});
            }
        });
    }
```

here I give more detail of my code

```
$id = (!empty($_REQUEST['id']) ? $_REQUEST['id'] : '');
    $filter1    = (!empty($_REQUEST['filter1']) ? $_REQUEST['filter1] : '');
    $filter2    = (!empty($_REQUEST['filter2']) ? $_REQUEST['filter2] : '');
    $filter3    = (!empty($_REQUEST['filter3']) ? $_REQUEST['filter3] : '');
    $filter4    = (!empty($_REQUEST['filter4']) ? $_REQUEST['filter4] : '');
    $filter5    = (!empty($_REQUEST['filter5']) ? $_REQUEST['filter5] : '');
    $filter6    = (!empty($_REQUEST['filter6']) ? $_REQUEST['filter6] : '');
    $filter7    = (!empty($_REQUEST['filter7']) ? $_REQUEST['filter7] : '');

    $where = '';
    if($id != ''){
        $where .= " AND a.id = $id ";
    }
    if($filter1 != ''){
        $where .= " AND a.filter1 >= '$filter1' ";
    }
    if($filter2 != ''){
        $where .= " AND a.filter2 <= '$filter2' ";
    }
    if($filter3 != ''){
        $where .= " AND a.filter3 = '$filter3' ";
    }
    if($filter4 != ''){
        $where .= " AND a.filter4 = $filter4 ";
    }
    if($filter5 != ''){
        $where .= " AND a.filter5 = $filter5 ";
    }
    if($filter6 != ''){
        $filter6 = json_encode($filter6);
        $filter6 = '';
        $i = 0;
        foreach($filter6 as $user){
            if($i > 0)
                $filter6 .=",";
            $filter6 .= "'$user'";
            $i++;
        }
        if($filter6 != "''"){
            $where .= " AND a.filter6 IN ($filter6)";   
        }
    }
    if($filter7 != ''){
        $filter7 = json_encode($filter7);
        $filter7 = '';
        $i = 0;
        foreach($filter7 as $equip){
            if($i > 0)
                $filter7 .=",";
            $filter7 .= "'$equip'";
            $i++;
        }
        if($filter7 != "''"){
            $where .= " AND a.filter7 IN ($filter7)";   
        }
    }
```

this is my php modal

```
<div id="menu-5" data-menu-size="440" class="menu-wrapper menu-light menu-top menu-large">
    <div class="menu-scroll">
        <div class="menu">
            <em class="menu-divider">Filter<i class="fa fa-navicon"></i></em>
            <div class="content" style="padding-left: 20px!important;padding-right: 20px!important;">
                <div class="input-simple-1 has-icon input-green full-bottom"><em>id:</em><i class="fa fa-list_ol"></i><input type="number" id="id" name="id" value=''></div>
                <div class="input-simple-1 has-icon input-green full-bottom"><em>Filter1:</em><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i><input type="date" id="Filter1" name="Filter1" value=''></div>
                <div class="input-simple-1 has-icon input-green full-bottom"><em>Filter2:</em><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i><input type="date" id="Filter2" name="Filter2" value=''></div>

                <div class="select-box select-box-1">
                    <em>Filter3:</em>
                    <?php filter3(); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="select-box select-box-1" >
                    <em>Filter4:</em>
                    <?php filter4(); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="form-group label-floating select2">
                        <label class="control-label">Filter5</label>
                        <?php Filter5(); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="form-group label-floating select2">
                        <label class="control-label">Filter6</label>
                        <?php Filter6(); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="content demo-buttons">
                <a href="javascript:filter();" class="button-full btn bg-green2-light close-menu" style="    margin: 3px 0;">Filter</a>
                <a href="example.php" class="button-full btn bg-blue-light close-menu" style="    margin: 3px 0;">Clear Filter</a>
                <a href="#" class="button-full btn bg-red-light close-menu" style="    margin: 3px 0;">close</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just save the filter in the localStorage using javascript, maybe in your ajax success callback. 
After refreshing the page, check the localStorage for the filter. If it exists, use ajax to load the filter to the DOM.

Comment: you can do a example?

Answer (score 0):

For stored data into the client side, there are many options but you need to choose based on your requirement like any storage limitation, which data value type, do you need Indexable? etc.

1. Cookie
2. Local Storage
3. IndexDB

Comment: Please find the localstorage example:
// Store
localStorage.setItem("lastname", "test");
// Retrieve
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");

Comment: Do you get chance to look into this?